# Where can I get schemas for liquid cooling

Tags: cooling

I want to install custom liquid cooling for CPU and GPU using 1 radiator and 1 pump. As I get from videos there are about 10 different schemas to do it. Where can I get some list of such schemas and recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

The radiator has to be connected to the pump.  The pump is connected to the CPU block, and that is connected to the GPU block.  The GPU block is then connected back to the radiator thus completing the loop.

This is done because the modern GPU can often get hotter than the CPU.

You can either use a special chemical, or water with an additive to kill any micro-organisms living in the water.